# Connect to SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm having trouble getting a connection to a `.sdf` (SQL Server Compact edition) database. When I debug my project in opening database appear this error:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll*
>
> *Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)*

I have no luck. I get this code:

```
Qconnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\New folder\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\Database1.sdf";
//connection.ConnectionString = " Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\Database1.sdf";
Qcommand.Connection = Qconnection;
Qconnection.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < orderColection.counter1; i++)
{
   string commandText = "Insert into order values(@RID,@amount,@type,@date)";
   Qcommand.CommandText = commandText;
   Qcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   Qcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RID", orderColection.list[i].rep_id);
   Qcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", orderColection.list[i].amount);
   Qcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", orderColection.list[i].type);
   Qcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", orderColection.list[i].date );
   Qcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Qconnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [System.Data.SqlServerCe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provider API to connect with SQL Server Compact data source. (Add the reference of `System.Data.SqlServerCe.Dll`).

```
using(SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\path\sample.sdf"))
{
 //
}
```